# How do I make a form update itself?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with 3 selections, and I want the form to replace the selected text with the name entered when submitted. So if the user enters their name as Josh, and picks 'King', I want the form to update itself and instead of having King it would say Josh which would no longer be a choice, and then have the other two characters below for someone else to pick from. This is a PHP document, but the data is in a HMTL form of course.

I was reading something about hidden forms, but was not sure how to implement them here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="character" value="King"> King<br>
  <input type="radio" name="character" value="Queen"> Queen<br>
  <input type="radio" name="character" value="Prince"> Prince <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Have you considered using javascript to achieve this?

Comment: No its just an exercise i'm trying to figure out in a PHP/HTML book. If there is a way using PHP, that would be helpful!

Comment: really can't understand what your trying to do . give sample output what you need

Comment: Do you mean a form with a hidden [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element (I.e- that has *type* attribute set the *hidden*- `<input type="hidden" />`)? Or do you mean a [*form*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element that itself is hidden?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aelliott/o5bk1uex/)?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to do something like this?

You can do it by using php conditions and hidden fields.

Save the file with the name "form.php" then run it and tell me if it does the trick ;)

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br/>
    <?php if((isset ($_POST['name-1']) || isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset ($_POST['character-1']) && $_POST['character-1']=='King'))
    {
        $name=isset($_POST['name-1'])?$_POST['name-1']:$_POST['name'];
        echo $name.'<br><input type="hidden" name="name-1" value="'.$name.'"/><input type="hidden" name="character-1" value="'. $_POST['character-1'].'"/>';
    }
    else {?>
        <input type="radio" name="character-1" value="King"> King<br>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if((isset ($_POST['name-2']) || isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset ($_POST['character-2']) && $_POST['character-2']=='Queen'))
    {
        $name=isset($_POST['name-2'])?$_POST['name-2']:$_POST['name'];
        echo $name.'<br><input type="hidden" name="name-2" value="'.$name.'"/><input type="hidden" name="character-2" value="'. $_POST['character-2'].'"/>';
    }
    else {?>
        <input type="radio" name="character-2" value="Queen"> Queen<br>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if((isset ($_POST['name-3']) || isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset ($_POST['character-3']) && $_POST['character-3']=='Prince'))
    {
        $name=isset($_POST['name-3'])?$_POST['name-3']:$_POST['name'];
        echo $name.'<br><input type="hidden" name="name-3" value="'.$name.'"/><input type="hidden" name="character-3" value="'. $_POST['character-3'].'"/>';
    }
    else {?>
        <input type="radio" name="character-3" value="Prince"> Prince <br>
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```